# Using isset to define an index not working

Tags: php, indexing, get, isset

This is something new to me, I have read and read on how to fix this.  My code has came a long way since.

When I started this piece I was going to define every request like so:

```
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'remove') {
  $theme = 'default theme applied';
    setcookie("drcstyleaccent", "", time() - 3600, '/');
}

if ($_GET['accent'] == 'light') {
  $theme = 'light';
  setcookie('drcstyleaccent', 'light', time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
}

echo $theme . 'theme applied';
```

Every theme was going to be defined in a separate get request with a new cookie / varible in each.

Since beginning my undefined index search, I have upgraded my script to:

```
$accent = isset($_GET['accent']) ? $_GET['accent'] : '';

if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'remove') {
    setcookie("drcstyleaccent", "", time() - 3600, '/');
} else {
  setcookie('drcstyleaccent', $accent, time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
}

echo $accent . ' theme applied';
```

From everything I have read this looks right to me, but I keep getting the undefined index error.  From what I've read `$accent = isset($_GET['accent']) ? $_GET['accent'] : '';` is defining the index...

I have tried also wrapping the `do` request with an `isset` but this should not be necessary because of the else right?

I know I can just disable the error with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` but I done want a "cheat".

I am ready for the down votes, I KNOW this has been covered here.  There are just too many topics on this to sift through them all, and all I have found have helped me to get to where I am now, and now I'm stuck.

Where am I going wrong with setting the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried also wrapping the do request with an isset but this should not be necessary because of the else right?

No. By running `$_REQUEST['do'] == 'remove'`, you are accessing `$_REQUEST` at index `'do'`. If this index is not defined, the *Undefined index* error is produced. To counter this, prepend the equality test with an `isset()`:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['do']) && $_REQUEST['do'] == 'remove') {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need the isset in the if. Regardless of the else. You are using an array item that may or may not exists.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['do']) and $_REQUEST['do'] == 'remove') {
```